# printing json data with combining whole data which is returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, printing

Here is my code

```
 public ActionResult PrintBarcodeLabel1(string data)
    {
      zplstr = zplstr + Environment.NewLine + zpl;
      return Json(zplstr, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here it will return

^XA

^FT90,85

^CI0

^A0N,38,52^FDAsset No.:^FS

^FT375,85

^A0N,38,52^FDSave ^FS

^FT90,173

sdfas^FS

^XZ

--new line through environment.new line and below

^XA

^FT90,85

^CI0

^A0N,38,52^FDAsset No.:^FS

^FT375,85

^A0N,38,52^FDSave ^FS

^FT90,173

sdfas^FS

^XZ

like this

but when i append it to a div or when i print data is binding or printing like this

^XA
^FT90,85
^CI0
^A0N,38,52^FDAsset No.:^FS
^FT375,85
^A0N,38,52^FDSave ^FS
^FT90,173
^A0N,38,52^FDAsset Name:^FS
^FT375,173
^A0N,38,52^FDSave ^FS
^FT90,261
^A0N,38,52^FDSerial No.:^FS
^XA
^FT90,85
^CI0
^A0N,38,52^FDAsset No.:^FS
^FT375,85
^A0N,38,52^FDSave ^FS
^FT90,173
^A0N,38,52^FDAsset Name:^FS
^FT375,173
^A0N,38,52^FDSave ^FS
^FT90,261
^A0N,38,52^FDSerial No.:^FS

this is my ajax print

```
var newWin = window.open();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: '/BarcodePrintTest/PrintBarcodeLabel1',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                if (data != "") {
                   // $('#my_cars_compare').html(data);
                    newWin.document.write('</head><body >');
                    newWin.document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                    newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
                    newWin.document.close();
                    newWin.focus();
                    newWin.print();
                    newWin.close();
                    window.location = '@Url.Action("Create", "BarcodePrintTest")';
                }

            },
```

Comment: Do you want line breaks in your html ?

Comment: yup exactly to print data in format which is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally got through this

```
$('#my_cars_compare').html(JSON.stringify(data.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br/>")));//.replace(/\r/g, "<br/>")
    newWin.document.write('</head><body >');
    newWin.document.write(JSON.stringify(data.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br/>")));
    newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
```

i convert to JSON.stringify  ...where i got seperator with \r\n finally i replaced \r\n with br tag

Thanks for all your responces

Comment: You do know that \r\n (carriage return\line feed) is a new line character - or as you have used it Environment.NewLine.

Comment: mmm, if you tried my answer you will not get `\r\n` in your `data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<br />` to represent line break in html.

Instead of

```
zplstr = zplstr + Environment.NewLine + zpl;
```

you can use

```
zplstr = zplstr + "<br />" + zpl;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still getting the issue with this solution ?

Comment: ya..data is clubing when binding to a div or in window.print() printing the data

Comment: Can you please put `console.log(data)` in the top of the `success: function (data) {` and let me know the result you get in console.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` instead of an `ActionResult`.

Comment: same thing is going no change  @colin

Comment: What type is zplstr? But I think @Saranga has identified your issue.

Comment: zplstr is of string type .

Comment: Debug your code. Copy the value of zplstr into a sample HTML page and see if it formats it as you expect it to. If not, there is an issue with the html markup being returned by the method PrintBarcodeLabel1. Check @Saranga's answer. Environment.NewLine will not display as a line break (<br />) in a browser.

Comment: while window.print() the whole data is combining in printout ..while i debug data returned upto to ajax is in correct format but coming to print it is clubing